# Insert Overwrite for multiple inserts in hive which have the same partition with same parameter value

Tags: insert, hive, partition

> Hi Guys,
>
> So I am trying to do multiple inserts and i am successfully able to
>   do it but if there are two queries which have same partition and
>   static value assigned it gives me the following error 
>   **:15:02:22 [EXPLAIN - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 10087, SQL State:
>   42000]  Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException
>   [Error 10087]: The same output cannot be present multiple times: 
>   table_name@id=0**
>   here first insert happens successfully but because second insert has the same value assigned for id 
>   which is 0 ..it gives the above error ..please let me know a 
>   workaround.Thanks :)

```
FROM (  
      Select * from Table_Name
     )Query
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE Table_Name PARTITION(id=0)
 select column1,column2,column3
 GROUP BY column1,column2,column1

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE Table_Name PARTITION(id=0) 
   select column1,count(*) as column2
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of multiple inserts, you can just do one insert with a union of the two queries.

```
FROM (  
      Select * from Table_Name
     )Query
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE Table_Name PARTITION(id=0)
  select <query 1>
  UNION ALL
  select <query 2>
```